# Laravel 4 nested resources logic issue

Tags: php, inheritance, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am working on a project that has an artists resource. The artist resource has a child resource called playlists. And further more playlists have another nested child called songs. So basically artists can have many playlists and in turn playlists can have many songs.

```
Route::resource('artists', 'ArtistsController');
Route::resource('artists.playlists', 'PlaylistsController');
Route::resource('artists.playlists.songs', 'SongsController');
```

When I try a simple get request at `/artists` everything is working fine and I am able to return all artists. Similarly a get request at `/artists/1` will return artist with id 1. The `/artists/1/playlists` will return all the playlists that belong to artist id 1 ie all playlists records with foreign key 1.

Now the problem I have is with the logic that when I access `/artists/1/playlists/1`, what should it return? Should it return the playlists with id 1 or the first playlist record that belongs to artist id 1.

The second one seems more logical to me but then I am running into other problems like how to handle delete request `/artists/1/playlists/1`, because I am trying to delete the first playlist of artist id 1 but I don't have it's id.

Maybe I don't exactly know how to handle nested resources properly because I am a newbie.
What should I do? Should I not nest them. And have separate resources for each. Like `/artists` and `/playlists` and `/songs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have a seperate controller for stuff like this.

You could have an artists controller and then a playlists controller which would have methods like `delete` or `create` or `edit`.

It keeps things more organized and ties them in to their own namespace.

Comment: I think OP has mentioned that he already has the controllers you are suggesting?